# Bucle While con falla en determinar algunos valores

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que me permita ingresar n numeros para calcular el promedio y determinar cual es el mayor y menor valor

```
n=int(input('Ingrese la cantidad de datos a procesar ')) # n es el numero de datos a tomar
i=0 # i es un contador
suma=0 
mayor=-999999
menor=999999
while i<=n:
   num=int(input('Ingrese un numero '))
   suma=suma+n # suma de todos los datos ingresados
   try:
      prom=suma/i # dividir la suma por la cantidad de datos contados
   except ZeroDivisionError:
      prom = 0  # evitar cualquier error si se digita un 0
   if mayor<n:
      mayor=n # definir al mayor
   if menor>n:
      menor=n  # definir el menor
   i+=1 //contador
print(prom) 
print(mayor)
print(menor)
```

La cosa es que no me da bien el promedio ni el menor.

Comment: porque comparas con n que vale siempre lo mismo?

Comment: Explicame tu codigo linea por linea, y de paso ponele a las variables nombres que se entiendan... y vas a ver donde falla tu logica....

Comment: Los comentarios se ponen con `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien el código funciona, hay cosas que pueden mejorar, por ejemplo: el promedio de ningún dato será *indefinido*, o al menos `False`. Además el programa fallará cuando `n = 0` y cuando el input de `num` sea un string no numérico.

Esta propuesta corrige los problemas anteriores. Además lo puse en un bucle infinito que sale con *doble Enter* y es cuando se hacen los cálculos, pero si quieres lo puedes adaptar a tu lógica:

```
mayor = None
menor = None
suma = 0
i = 0
print('Calcular promedio. Deje [en blanco] y [ENTER] para procesar')
while True:
    num = input(f'Ingrese el numero {i+1}: ')
    if num == '':
        break # Salir
    try:
        num = int(num) # Convertir str a int
    except:
        print('Este dato no es valido, reintente')
        continue
    suma += num
    if mayor==None or num>mayor:
        mayor = num
    if menor==None or num<menor:
        menor = num
    i += 1

print()
promedio = None if i==0 else suma/i
print('Datos ingresados:', i)
print('Suma de los datos:', suma)
print('El promedio es:', promedio)
print('El dato mayor es:', mayor)
print('El dato menor es:', menor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya vi mi error

```
n=int(input('Ingrese la cantidad de datos a procesar '))
i=1
suma=0
mayor=-999999
menor=999999
while i<=n:
   num=int(input('Ingrese un numero '))
   suma=suma+num
   try:
       prom=suma/i
   except ZeroDivisionError:
       prom = 0 
   if mayor<num:
       mayor=num
   if menor>num:
       menor=num
   i+=1
print('El promedio de los datos es igual a ',prom)
print('El dato mayor es',mayor)
print('El dato menor es ',menor)
```

Ya vi mi error y era que yo no estaba diferenciando entre el 'n'  y el 'num', por eso no me arrojaba los valores correctos, la solucion era simplemente cambiar 'n' por 'num' que es la variabale en la que se almacena el valor que ingreso.